# Html base href rewriting get first 404 after 200

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor app under the sub directory of an site on IIS. To fix blazor wasm base path problem, applied javascript code below in the head tag (suggested on elmah.io: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-fix-blazor-wasm-base-path-problems/)

```html
<!-- omitted for clarity -->
<head>
  <base />
  <script>
      var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      var base = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
      if (window.location.host.includes('localhost')) {
          base.setAttribute('href', '/MyApp/');
      } else if (path.length > 2) {
          let href = '/' + path[1] + '/MyApp/';
          base.setAttribute('href', href);
      } else if (path[path.length - 1].length != 0) {
          let fullpath = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '/' + window.location.search;
          window.location.replace(fullpath);
      }
  </script>
</head>
```

It works pretty well and solve the blazor base path problem. But, when you enter the app url without ending with '/', the developer console fills up with 404 (not found) errors and then all of them turns out 200 (ok) ok for all css/js files. Why is it do that and can i fix it?

[image: console]
[image: In the network view all of resources get first 404 after 200]

Comment: Is the path for the SPA and the resources it uses fixed?  i.e. say at "https://xxxxx/WASM"?  If so what's wrong with using fixed path information.  Here's a solution I use to host both WASM and Server on the same site - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Blazor-AllinOne.html

Comment: Yes, all resources are fixed but we have to serve our app in some "virtual path" on server. i.e. https://server.com/somevirtualpath/MyApp
If app belongs with root path directly (i.e. https://server.com/MyApp) already no need to add the javascript code at the head tag.